# Dual monitor setup no longer works!

Tags: multiple-monitors, fedora

Running Fedora 14 with a Nvidia GeForce 9500 card

Couple of days ago I replaced one of my 20" LCD (I had two identical 20") w/ a 24" LCD. I was able to swap the 20 for the new 24" and of course the display was distorted due to the resolution. So, I backed up my xorg.conf file and decided to run nvidia-setting to configure the resolution. I rebooted and viola, only one monitor works, the 24". The other refuses to come on and I have no idea why. I'm wondering if the one DVI port is bad. I swapped the two DVI cables and output to my 20" works but my 24 turns black. The only thing that change was a simple swap of monitors.

Here's my xorg.conf file:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "Xinerama" "1"
    Option "AIGLX" "on"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "Layout0"
    Screen 0 "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen 1 "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/default/Type1"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier "Mouse0"
    Driver "mouse"
    Option "Protocol" "auto"
    Option "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from data in "/etc/sysconfig/keyboard"
    Identifier "Keyboard0"
    Driver "kbd"
    Option "XkbLayout" "us"
    Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
   # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier "Monitor0"
    VendorName "Unknown"
    ModelName "AOC 2436"
    HorizSync 30.0 - 80.0
    VertRefresh 56.0 - 75.0
    Option "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier "Monitor1"
    VendorName "Unknown"
    ModelName "Samsung SyncMaster"
    HorizSync 30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh 56.0 - 75.0
    Option "DPMS"
    Option "RandRRotation" "on"
    Option "Rotate" "CCW"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device0"
    Driver "nvidia"
    VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName "GeForce 9500 GT"
    BusID "PCI:2:0:0"
    Screen 0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device1"
    Driver "nvidia"
    VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName "GeForce 9500 GT"
    BusID "PCI:2:0:0"
    Screen 1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device "Device0"
    Monitor "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth 24
    Option "TwinView" "0"
    Option "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device "Device1"
    Monitor "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth 24
    Option "TwinView" "0"
    Option "metamodes" "DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```